# React ignoring CSS class, not IDs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am very new to React, so I might be asking something *really trivial*, but after a while, it seems to me dark magic that I can't make something as simple as applying a style work properly.

I am [following this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRaelG7v0OU), something easy. Until I get to the point where I need to apply styles. React **consistently** ignores all my styles.

The CSS I am using is straightforward, I changed also the background of the `body` to see if it works, but it is ignored:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
};

body {
    background-color: #ffa3a3; /*#f3f3f3;*/
    margin: 100px;
}

.container.ql-editor {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

Whereas the text editor JS file is almost like the tutorial:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import Quill from 'quill'
import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
// import "./styles.css";

export default function TextEditor() {
  const wrapperRef = useCallback((wrapper) => {
    if (wrapper == null) return;

    wrapper.innerHTML = "";
    const editor =  document.createElement("div");

    wrapper.append(editor);
    new Quill(editor,  { theme: "snow" });
  }, []);
 
  return (
    <div id="container" ref={wrapperRef}></div>
  )
}
```

As you can see, out of desperation, I added the import of the CSS everywhere without any results. Also, changing to `<div className="container" ref={wrapperRef}></div>` does not help.

But I see that **IDs work**:

```
#container {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

I have tried all the combination of classes, since the QuillJS version I have has a different HTML generation from the tutorial, in my version the outline of the HTML is:

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div id="container">
            <div class="ql-toolbar ql-snow">...</div>
            <div class="ql-container ql-snow">
                <div class="ql-editor ql-blank">...</div>
                <div class="ql-clipboard">...</div>
                <div class="ql-tooltip ql-hidden"></div>
            </div>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Alex is correct on the styling. Also, in JSX, you can’t use the word class. You have to use className instead. JSX gets translated into JS, and class is a reserved word in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a space between `.container` and `.ql-editor`

```
.container .ql-editor {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

Without the space, the selector targets all elements with both 'container' and  'ql-editor' class.

With the space, the selector targets all elements with class 'ql-editor' that are descendents of an element with class 'container'

Comment: Oh man, that solved it! So a space is an OR... well, I might have never found out. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to have helped. A space is not quite an OR though. You can read more on it here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Comment: Thanks, I now see better how it works!